# How to add paraeters in routing Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I tried to add parameters to route in Laravel for resource:

```
Route::resource('place', 'Dashboard\PlaceController', ["parameters" => ["roles" => "Admin"]]);
```

Then I display route array:

```
$actions = $request->route()->getAction();
        dd($actions);
```

And I get array without parameter `roles`:

```
array:7 [▼
  "middleware" => array:3 [▶]
  "as" => "place.index"
  "uses" => "App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\PlaceController@index"
  "controller" => "App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\PlaceController@index"
  "namespace" => "App\Http\Controllers"
  "prefix" => null
  "where" => []
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an artisan command you can use to check what routes you have and it's `php artisan route:list`.

I think the problem here is that you are using `Route::resource`, as per [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers) it fills your routes with pre-defined usually useful endpoints for CRUD.

If you want more power over the parameters I suggest you overwrite some of the routes putting routing lines just right before your `Route::resource`.

Usually I tend to remove routes from a resource route using `only` or `except` to reduce them like:

```
Route::resource('photo', 'PhotoController', ['only' => [
    'index', 'show'
]]);
```

I don't think it would be even possible to add more(not in the same line, I mean).

TLDR: Don't use `Route::resource()` if you need customized routes, use `Route::get()` and `Route::post()` instead, adding route parameters in curly braces like

```
Route::get('/users/{username}', 'UsersController@show');
```